# Show different icons for different status options in orders grid in magento 2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I have added a custom field in sales_order table and showing it in sales_order_grid  table in backend. It is working fine. I have done the following to achieve this
I have added `sales_order_grid.xml` file in following location

> \magento2\app\code\Plenty\Orders\view\adminhtml\ui_component\sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="plenty_status" class="Plenty\Orders\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status">
            <settings>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <options class="Plenty\Orders\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status\Options"/>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Plenty Status</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Now my Status.php class that is rendering the data in the grid

```
\magento2\app\code\Plenty\Orders\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status.php class that is acting as renderer
```

Content of the above class

```
<?php
namespace Plenty\Orders\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

class Status extends Column
{
protected $_orderRepository;
protected $_searchCriteria;

public function __construct(
    ContextInterface $context,
    UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
    OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria,
    array $components = [],
    array $data = [])
{
    $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
    parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
}

public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {

            $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
            $status = $order->getData("plenty_status");

            switch ($status) {
                case \Plenty\Orders\Model\Order\Status::STATUS_NEW;
                    $plenty_status = "Order placed before plenty markets extension was installed";
                    break;
                case \Plenty\Orders\Model\Order\Status::STATUS_PENDING;
                    $plenty_status = "Pending";
                    break;
                case \Plenty\Orders\Model\Order\Status::STATUS_PROCESSING;
                    $plenty_status = "Processing";
                    break;
                case \Plenty\Orders\Model\Order\Status::STATUS_COMPLETE;
                    $plenty_status = "Complete";
                    break;
                case \Plenty\Orders\Model\Order\Status::STATUS_CANCELLED;
                    $plenty_status = "Canceled";
                    break;
                case \Plenty\Orders\Model\Order\Status::STATUS_UPDATED;
                    $plenty_status = "Updated";
                    break;
                case \Plenty\Orders\Model\Order\Status::STATUS_FAILED;
                    $plenty_status = "Failed";
                    break;          
                default:
                    $plenty_status = "Plenty Status not found";
                    break;

            }

            // $this->getData('name') returns the name of the column so in this case it would return export_status
            $item[$this->getData('name')] = $plenty_status;
        }
    }

    return $dataSource;
}
```

}

Everything is working fine. Statuses are showing properly in orders grid. Now my issue is I want to show different icons for different statuses. I want to use font awesome icons which is already included in my website. But when I make following changes in my code to show icons

```
case \Plenty\Orders\Model\Order\Status::STATUS_PENDING;
    $html .= '<i class="fa fa-clock-o pending" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
                    $statusToolTip = __('Order Synchronisation Pending');
                    break;
```

Then I am getting html in the orders grid also. Screenshot
[image]

So Please guide me what I should do or try to show icons in my order grid for plenty status field.

Screenshot of what I want to achieve.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had faced similar issue like this, I'd fixed it as you can see in below Image, Please follow steps.

[image]

**Add this line in sales_order_grid.xml => `<bodyTmpl>ui/grid/cells/html</bodyTmpl>`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="plenty_status" class="Plenty\Orders\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status">
            <settings>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <options class="Plenty\Orders\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status\Options"/>
                <bodyTmpl>ui/grid/cells/html</bodyTmpl>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Plenty Status</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**Also change this line in your status file
`app\code\Plenty\Orders\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status.php`**

`$item[$this->getData('name')] = html_entity_decode($plenty_status);`

```
<?php
namespace Plenty\Orders\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

class Status extends Column
{
protected $_orderRepository;
protected $_searchCriteria;

public function __construct(
    ContextInterface $context,
    UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
    OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria,
    array $components = [],
    array $data = [])
{
    $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
    parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
}

public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {

            $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
            $status = $order->getData("plenty_status");

            switch ($status) {
                case \Plenty\Orders\Model\Order\Status::STATUS_NEW;
                    $plenty_status = "Order placed before plenty markets extension was installed";
                    break;
                case \Plenty\Orders\Model\Order\Status::STATUS_PENDING;
                    $plenty_status = "Pending";
                    break;
                case \Plenty\Orders\Model\Order\Status::STATUS_PROCESSING;
                    $plenty_status = "Processing";
                    break;
                case \Plenty\Orders\Model\Order\Status::STATUS_COMPLETE;
                    $plenty_status = "Complete";
                    break;
                case \Plenty\Orders\Model\Order\Status::STATUS_CANCELLED;
                    $plenty_status = "Canceled";
                    break;
                case \Plenty\Orders\Model\Order\Status::STATUS_UPDATED;
                    $plenty_status = "Updated";
                    break;
                case \Plenty\Orders\Model\Order\Status::STATUS_FAILED;
                    $plenty_status = "Failed";
                    break;          
                default:
                    $plenty_status = "Plenty Status not found";
                    break;

            }

            // $this->getData('name') returns the name of the column so in this case it would return export_status
            $item[$this->getData('name')] = html_entity_decode($plenty_status);
        }
    }

    return $dataSource;
}
```

Hope this will help you. Thanks.